# Cannot invoke an Objective-C method in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-plot

I am trying to rewrite an Objective-C code sample in Swift. The code basically draw a graph using CorePlot, which is written in Objective-C (the sample is from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2)). Here is a piece of the original Objective-C code:

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
```

I rewrite it like this:

```
var xRange = plotSpace.plotRangeForCoordinate(CPTCoordinate.X).mutableCopy() as CPTMutablePlotRange;
xRange.expandRangeByFactor(NSDecimalNumber(1.1))
```

At this point I have a compile error saying that "`CPTMutablePlotRage does not have a member named 'expandRangeByFactor'`". Anybody know if I did anything wrong? I checked and in Objective-C code, CTMutablePotRange definitely has a method called `expandRangeByFactor.` Thanks.

Comment: Note that Swift 1.2 can deal with NSDecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expandRangeByFactor` exists, but it takes an NSDecimal. You are trying to supply an NSDecimalNumber, which is not the same thing. (Another problem with your code - irrelevant in this situation, but still a problem - is that you cannot say `NSDecimalNumber(1.1)`. There is no such initializer.)

You need to pass an NSDecimal parameter here. That is why the original Objective-C code calls the Core Plot function `CPTDecimalFromCGFloat()` - to generate the NSDecimal that goes here.

However, you can't do that in Swift because it doesn't know about NSDecimal. Thus, Swift cannot see this method no matter what you do, because it can't see a method that takes a value of a type that it can't deal with.

The Core Plot people are aware of this issue: see https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/96 The new `release-2.0` branch contains a fix. As you can see [here](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/release-2.0/framework/Source/CPTMutablePlotRange.h), in the new API you can just pass an NSNumber to `expandRangeByFactor`.

**Update**: Swift 1.2 (available in Xcode 6.3 and later) can deal with NSDecimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read from somewhere that NSDecimal is not supported in Swift. So looks like I hit a dead end here. I wish, though, that swift just tell me that that method does not take that parameter or something like that. May be that method was not even bridge to swift at all because of the NSDecimal. For NSDecimalNumber initialization, probably you are right but I did not hit with the error yet because the compiler probably stop before it hit that sot

Comment: According to [this discussion](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/96) you can find a revised Core Plot API that doesn't use NSDecimal at release-2.0 branch of Core Plot on github.

Comment: You can pass an NSNumber if you use the release-2.0 version of Core  Plot.

Comment: Thanks matt. I am thinking about waiting for CorePlot to merge it back to master. Meanwhile I want to try this solution here instead: http://blog.alwold.com/2014/09/03/coreplot-nsdecimal-and-swift/

Comment: Right, I pointed to that in an earlier version of my answer, but I took it out because it isn't really relevant to the question you asked. I doubt there is much danger to just adopting the new branch of core plot, though!

Comment: I also find that your answer addresses my question thoroughly already, which is why I accepted it. Thanks again - I think it will help me clearing this issue.